# AuthorizationException not handled in Handler.php Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

Hello I have a problem with exception handler in Laravel 5.4.

I have in my controller a function that make a check for permission like:

```
function foo(){
   try{ 
      $this->authorize("bar", MyClass::class);
   }catch(AuthorizationException $e){

   }
}
```

In my handler.php I have this:

```
    namespace App\Exceptions;

use Exception;
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
 protected $dontReport = [
        \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException::class,
        \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException::class,
        \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException::class,
        \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException::class,
    ];
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {

        if ($exception instanceof AuthorizationException) {
            if ($request->expectsJson()) {
                return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized.'], 403);
            }
            // TODO: Redirect to error page instead
        }
        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
}
```

But the problem is that handler is never called.
But If I do:

```
function foo(){
   try{ 
      throw new AuthorizationException() //test for throw exception
      $this->authorize("bar", MyClass::class);

   }catch(AuthorizationException $e){

   }
}
```

It will call handler.

So Can I handler AuthorizationException  with **$this->authorize** ?

Comment: Do you have `use Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException;` in handler.php ?

Comment: thakyou for reply, but yes,  I will edt my question! but the problem is that I try to put dd("test"), it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Now I've resolve in this way:
I created a Custom class that extends AuthorizationException like:

```
namespace App\Exceptions;
namespace Illuminate\Auth\Access;
use Throwable;
class CustomAuthorizationException extends AuthorizationException
    {
            public function __construct($message = "", $code = 0, Throwable $previous = null)
            {
                throw new AuthorizationException();

            }
    }
```

And In Controller:

```
function foo(){
   try{ 

      $this->authorize("bar", MyClass::class);

   }catch(CustomAuthorizationException $e){

   }
}
```

And now it works, but I don't know if It is a good way.
The advices are well accepted!